# Gap on right and left sides in areaChart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Charts to visualize some data. When drawing full width chart in bordered container I can see small gaps on the left and right side. Is it possible to remove it? The chart area width is set to 100%.

[image]

JS:

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales'],
    ['2013',  1000],
    ['2014',  1170],
    ['2015',  660],
    ['2016',  1030]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      textPosition: 'none',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    },
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    chartArea: {
      'width': '100%',
      'height': '100%',
      'backgroundColor': '#fff'
    },
    colors: ['#ddd'],
    height: 50,

    lineWidth: 0,
    areaOpacity: 1,
    annotations: {
      stemColor : 'none'
    },
    tooltip : {
      trigger: 'none'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
     <div id="chart"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5m6fLckw/5/

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle link? Which browser are you using? What is the container element having the border?

Comment: Use jsFiddle to provide your code

Comment: @MariosNikolaou - done - https://jsfiddle.net/5m6fLckw/5/

Comment: @Mamun - done - jsfiddle.net/5m6fLckw/5

Comment: .flt-phase { border: 0px solid #ddd; }

Comment: @MariosNikolaou border on the container has been added on purpose. There is a gap between border and cart which I need to remove.